# Оцените, поправьте

Tags: стилистика

Несмотря на избитую истину насчет общественного строя этого государства, кое-что, на мой взгляд, можно отнести к проявлению свободы: для иностранца передвижение по территории не ограничено какими-то запретами.

(*Имеется в виду, что Куба в чём-то свободнее Северной Кореи*.)

Answer (score 1):

- Если вы говорите о некоей избитой истине, желательно ее как-то обозначить, а не заставлять читателя догадываться.  Например, "избитая истина о **жескости/деспотичност/несправедливости** общественного строя".
- Если вы говорите "кое-что", то желательно обозначить из какого набора взято это "кое-что". Например: "Кое-что **из фактов общественной жизни**, на мой взгляд, можно отнести к проявлению свободы".
- Другой вариант: Кое в чем, на мой взгляд, можно найти проявления свободы".
- Двоеточие желательно заменить на слова "к примеру".
- Передвижение по территории (чего?) страны

**Несмотря на избитую истину насчет деспотичности общественного строя этого государства, кое в чем, на мой взгляд, можно найти  проявления свободы; к примеру, для иностранца передвижение по территории страны не ограничено какими-то запретами.**

Comment: Правка понравилось. Только, насчет «деспотичности» - слишком сурово.

Comment: @Виктор "тоталитарность" звучит лучше? По определению, это когда политическая власть берёт общество под полный  контроль. Но тогда лучше убрать "общественный строй" ---- Несмотря на избитую истину насчет тоталитарности этого государства, кое в чем, на мой взгляд, можно найти проявления свободы; к примеру, для иностранца передвижение по территории страны не ограничено какими-то запретами.

Comment: Нет, «тоталитарность» тоже не лучше. Я ведь не главу для учебника пишу, а путевые заметки, зачем такие слова трибунные. Вообще-то Кубу "Островом свободы" называют. Находясь там, ночевал на вокзалах и пустырях, и меня не забрали в КПЗ. А про деспотизм, или его отсутствие, уместно рассуждать, отправляясь в качестве дипломата. Я бы оставил свой вариант, не уточняя: читатель сам должен додумать, каким он представляет общественный строй Кубы. Или написал бы так: «не очень демократичного».

Comment: 1.Если вы считаете, что отсутствие свободы на острове - истина, тогда "вопреки избитой истине". Но если вы считаете, что это всего лишь распространенное мнение, тогда я бы посоветовал сказать "вопреки ходячему мнению". 2.Слово "вопреки" предполагает противопоставление "свобода - несвобода". "Не очень демократичное" плохо подходит для такого противопоставления. "Тоталитарное" - подходит. Хотите более простым языком? Как вариант, можно написать: "Вопреки избитой истине/ходячему мнению о том, что все находится под контролем у государства, кое в чем, на мой взгляд, можно найти проявления свободы"

Answer (score 0):

Несмотря на общеизвестные истины об ограничении гражданских свобод и жесткой цензуре на Кубе, кое-что, на мой взгляд, можно отнести к проявлению конституционных прав. К примеру, для иностранца передвижение по территории государства не ограничено никакими запретами (всё же  хоть в чем-то Куба свободнее Северной Кореи).

Пояснение: Недостатки общественного строя лучше как-то конкретно обозначить.

Comment: Стиль - слишком хрестоматийный: будто цитата из учебника...

Comment: 1) Начало текста неудачно построено, его надо как-то поправить.  2) Однокоренные слова "свобода", "свободнее" надо разместить подальше друг от друга. 3) В последнем предложении в скобках почему использовано прошедшее время (кстати, предложенный вариант в скобках короче вашего и явно относится к разговорному стилю).

Comment: В скобках - это не вариант, а часть вопроса: разъяснение, о чем речь.